# Python function is skipping a segment when called for a second time

Tags: python, function

This is the minimum code i could write which replicates the problem i'm having in my larger piece of code, it is for python 3.4.2

The main problem is that i'm having trouble calling my functions correctly.
I can go through the program once perfectly fine, but then when i try and restart the program by calling the "PrisonCellSize" function again, the input section is completely skipped, does anyone know a way to fix this? I thought that because i reset roomheight and roomsize to "0" it would require an input from the user again? instead it completely skips the input section, does it perhaps have anything to do with my intendation?

I'm extremely new to this so i apologize if i have made a blatant error but i have tried troubleshooting for an extremely long time before giving up and asking you geniuses :P I would be grateful for any help towards fixing this issue Python version: 3.4.2

TLDR;The "PrisonCellSize" function when called for a second time does not ask for an input from the user

EDIT: Formatting, i hope this is clearer for everyone

```
def PrisonCellSize():
    global TotalRoomSize    
    #calculates size of the room
roomheight = 0
roomwidth = 0

roomwidth = float(input("Enter your total room width, make sure it is between 5 and 10 metres:\n"))
roomheight = float(input("Enter the room height, it must be between 1m-4m: \n")) 
if ((roomwidth <=10 and roomwidth >=5) and (roomheight <=4 and roomheight >=1)):
    print ("Thankyou for your input\n")

else: print ("\nError, please enter the correct amounts")

def NextFunction():
    input ("Did you want a window:\n")

def restart():
    print ("restarting program\n")
    print ("--------------------")
    PrisonCellSize()
    NextFunction()
    restart()

    return  




#start of program

PrisonCellSize()
NextFunction()
restart()
```

And my output was as follows:

```
"================================ RESTART ================================ 
Enter your total room width, make sure it is between 5 and 10 metres:
"8"
Enter the room height, it must be between 1m-4m: 
"2"
Thankyou for your input

Did you want a window:
"yes"
restarting program

--------------------
Did you want a window:
"yes"
restarting program

--------------------
Did you want a window:
"yes"
restarting program

--------------------
Did you want a window:"
```

Comment: Your biggest mistake is not formatting the source code properly in the question! Python is whitespace sensitive.

Comment: I think you need to go back to whatever book or reference it is that you're using to learn Python, and make sure you understand what a function actually is and how it works.

Comment: Sorry, when I fix the indentation in your code, it does not run like you say; that is I cannot repeat your bug...

Answer (score 0):

```
def PrisonCellSize():
    global TotalRoomSize    
    #calculates size of the room
    roomheight = 0
    roomwidth = 0

    roomwidth = float(input("Enter your total room width, make sure it is between 5 and 10 metres:\n"))
    roomheight = float(input("Enter the room height, it must be between 1m-4m: \n")) 
    if ((roomwidth <=10 and roomwidth >=5) and (roomheight <=4 and roomheight >=1)):
        print ("Thankyou for your input\n")

    else: print ("\nError, please enter the correct amounts")

def NextFunction():
    input ("Did you want a window:\n")

def restart():
    print ("restarting program\n")
    print ("--------------------")
    PrisonCellSize()
    NextFunction()
    restart()

    return
```